# If the old app using GCM does not have plans to migrate to FCM ,What happens post April 2019?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

Does the old app using GCM still work if the app is not migrated to FCM post April 2019 by changing only the server end point to FCM ?

And from the [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq):

"Note that client SDKs and GCM tokens will continue to work indefinitely. However, you won't be able to target the latest version of Google Play Services in your Android app unless you migrate to FCM."

Does it mean that, at the client side if the app uses GCM services and tries to update/target Google play services released after 2019 April then the app won't compile due to removing of gcm services from play services(com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:x.x.x) , so if the app want to use latest version of Google play services , only option is to use FCM as GCM code won't compile . 
Is my understanding correct ?

Post April 2019. if the app. does not target latest version of Google play services ,can it submit future versions of app using GCM  in playstore without migrating to FCM ?